# Relative path resolution differences between Windows & Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, fopen, relative-path

Given a file `text.txt` in the CWD I'm getting two different answers from `fopen()` to the question "does this file exist?" for `a/b/../../test.txt` (which reduces to just `test.txt`):

- Windows: file exists
- Linux: file *doesn't*(!) exist

However, if I then `mkdir -p a/b` Linux changes its tune and says that `a/b/../../test.txt` exists now.

It's as if Linux checks that each directory exists as it processes the relative path (and early outs if any of them don't) instead of collapsing any `../`'s first and then doing the file-exists check like Windows appears to do.

Two questions:

- How can I get Linux to behave like Windows does in this instance?  Like some sort of environment variable to modify glibc/syscall behavior.
- How *should* `fopen()` behave with relative paths like this?  The documentation/specifications I could turn up for `fopen()` simply indicated it accepted relative paths (perhaps with a few examples), not how those paths should be resolved in the case of mid-path `../`'s.

Test program:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

void file_exists( const char* filename )
{
    FILE* file = fopen( filename, "r" );
    std::cout << ( file ? "Y" : "N" ) << ": " << filename << std::endl;
    if( file )
    {
        fclose( file );
    }
}

int main( int, char** )
{
    // initial tests
    std::filesystem::remove( "test.txt" );
    std::filesystem::remove( "doesnt-exist.txt" );
    file_exists( "test.txt" );
    file_exists( "doesnt-exist.txt" );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // create file
    std::cout << "creating text.txt..." << std::endl;
    std::ofstream output( "test.txt", std::ios::trunc );
    output << "test" << std::endl;
    output.close();

    // more tests
    file_exists( "test.txt" );
    file_exists( "doesnt-exist.txt" );
    file_exists( "a/b/../../test.txt" );
    file_exists( "a/b/../../doesnt-exist.txt" );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "creating directory 'a/b'..." << std::endl;
    std::filesystem::create_directories( "a/b" );
    file_exists( "a/b/../../test.txt" );
    file_exists( "a/b/../../doesnt-exist.txt" );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // cleanup
    std::filesystem::remove( "test.txt" );
    std::filesystem::remove_all( "a/b" );

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

- Windows 10, VS2017:

  ```
  N: test.txt
  N: doesnt-exist.txt

  creating text.txt...
  Y: test.txt
  N: doesnt-exist.txt
  Y: a/b/../../test.txt          # file exists, expected behavior
  N: a/b/../../doesnt-exist.txt

  creating directory 'a/b'...
  Y: a/b/../../test.txt
  N: a/b/../../doesnt-exist.txt
  ```
- Ubuntu 20.04, `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0`

  ```
  N: test.txt
  N: doesnt-exist.txt

  creating text.txt...
  Y: test.txt
  N: doesnt-exist.txt
  N: a/b/../../test.txt          # file *doesn't* exist, unexpected behavior
  N: a/b/../../doesnt-exist.txt

  creating directory 'a/b'...
  Y: a/b/../../test.txt
  N: a/b/../../doesnt-exist.txt
  ```

Comment: The Windows behavior may be more convenient for you in this case, but I think the Ubuntu behaviour appears more 'correct'.  If the path is specified in this way, perhaps it should be different than specifying c/d/../../text.txt.  if "a/b" or "c/d" (whichever specified) does not exist, the path as written is one which does not make sense.

Comment: I doubt this is something the language standard says anything about, posix might and that would have bearing on the linux behavior but windows is not a posix platform. And I would actually be surprised if fopen (or even open) do any processing rather relying on the OS to say whether the file exists.

Comment: The Windows behavior is the expected one on that platform, since (most) other apps work that way. It boils down to path resolution using [GetFullPathName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamew) which is documented to "*not verify that the resulting path and file name are valid*". Don't know that C++ mandates any particular behavior for relative paths.

Comment: You could write a path string collapser to make x/../ disappear, recursively, returning a new string.

Comment: The underlying NT system in Windows has no support for "." and ".." components in paths, other than reserving the names in some filesystems (e.g. NTFS reserves them; FAT32 does not and allows creating files named "." and ".."). So the Windows API has to resolve them as a purely string operation when normalizing a path as an NT path (e.g. normalizing the path in `CreateFileW` before calling `NtCreateFile`).

Comment: @Basya: You'd certainly hope that the OS would check the permissions of `b` in `a`.

Comment: @dxiv: [The cppreference page for `std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) indicates path normalization is done Windows-style, with no filesystem checks.

Comment: @genpfault Good to know, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: An exception is filesystem relative symbolic links in NT, which are reparsed in the kernel relative to the path of the symlink with semantics similar to Unix -- if and only if components exist (i.e. no problem with non-existent "a" and "b"). This is the proper way, since resolving ".." naively to remove a symlink (e.g. "symlink/../spam") may result in a completely different target path. Thus handling of ".." components is self-inconsistent in Windows, and this makes manually resolving relative symlinks in Windows (e.g. via a readlink implementation) extremely difficult compared to Unix.

Answer (score 3):

[std::filesystem::path::lexically_normal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal) might help to normalize path purely lexically (Doesn't follow symlink, check existence of path, ...).

So `fopen(std::filesystem::path{"a/b/../../test.txt"}.lexically_normal().c_str(), "r")` will act identically. (You have indeed to wrap your call to have that behavior).

Answer (score 1):

File- and pathnames are implementation-specific. This makes obvious sense when you realize that `C:X` is an entirely valid filename in Linux and Windows, but with very different meanings.

On Linux (like UNIX), `..` is a real directory entry. That is to say, `a/b/../../` involves 4 real directory entries: a and b obviously, but also `..` in b and `..` in a. `fopen` needs to do nothing special: the OS just checks actual directory entries.

On Windows, the path `a/b/../../` must first be converted to the standard format. That is to say, it should begin with `\??\`. You may not have seen these paths before, but they're what Windows uses internally. All such paths are absolute paths, and these **always** contain backslashes. The translation from `a/b/../../` therefore involves prefixing the current working drive and directory, replacing `\` with `/` and removing `..`

As you can see, these are entirely different ways of resolving `..`. Your `fopen` call just follows the local convention, generally by just passing the string to the OS. (But on Windows `fopen` might also do the `/\` conversion in advance,just to be sure.)

If another OS would choose `^`  to mean "parent directory", you'd expect `fopen("a/b/^/^")` to follow that convention as well, so it's not like `..` is a special string. On such a platform, `..` might even be a valid name for a subdirectory.

Comment: Note that if you use a verbatim "\\?\" path in Windows, you can actually create a file named ".." in a FAT32 filesystem. It's distinguished from the normal ".." entry in a non-root directory listing by the presence of an auto-generated 8.3 short name.